# Поток при инициализации сразу запускает функцию

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Делаю большой студенческий проект, в котором для оптимизация алгоритма нечёткого поиска требуется распараллеливать вычисления. Во время проверки всего и вся обнаружил, что поток при своей инициализации почему-то сразу запускает функцию, подумал, что совсем опешил, создал новый чистый проект, написал маленький код там и снова увидел, что поток при инициализации сразу стартует функцию. В примере ниже, сразу при запуске программы, сообщение "hi" мгновенно бесконечно выводится на экран.

```c
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;

void fu()
{
    for (;;)
        cout << "hi";
}

int main()
{
    thread th(fu);
    Sleep(1000000);
}
```

Как я читал, для того, чтоб поток стартанул, требуется `join()` или `detach()`, но здесь поток стартует функцию без данных изысков, ничего не понимаю...

[image: При запуске программы вижу это]

Comment: *"Как я читал, для того, чтоб поток стартанул, требуется join() или detach()"*, нет `join()` или `detach()` ничего такого не делают и поток всегда стартует сразу. Если вам надо, чтобы поток чего-то ждал, то следует добавить условие и condition variable и в функции потока запускать ожидание этого условия.

Comment: Но тогда для чего они нужны, если поток запускается самостоятельно? В интернете об этом ничего не нашёл.

Comment: `join` нужен для ожидания *завершения* потока и обязательно должен вызываться до вызова деструктора запущенного потока. `detach` обычно не нужен, см https://stackoverflow.com/a/58222149/7860670

Comment: *"В интернете об этом ничего не нашёл."* - не верю, первая же ссылка в бинге подробно рассказывает зачем они нужны -  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join

Comment: Искал по запросу "поток запускается сразу при инициализации"

Comment: Собственно на том же сайте есть описание эффектов от вызова конструктора потока...

Comment: А если мне требуется некую бесконечно работающую функцию закинуть в поток отдельный? У меня же тогда главный поток при использовании ```join()``` просто ничего не будет делать.

Comment: Нормальные программы не должны содержать никаких бесконечно работающих функций. В любом потоке следует делать какой-то флаг по которому функция потока должна завершаться, завершая поток и разблокировать `join` в родительском потоке.

Comment: Просто в моём случае требуется держать сокет и отвечать на запросы логики сайта. Разве такое можно сделать без бесконечного цикла?)

Comment: Такое без проблем можно сделать не только без бесконечного цикла, но и без фонового потока. Смотрите асинхронный ввод/вывод

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю!

Comment: Если проект чисто под винду, то как вариант можно работать с потоками напрямую через Windows API. Так, функция `CreateThread()` может принимать флаг `CREATE_SUSPENDED`, создавая поток сразу приостановленым. Запустить выполнение можно с помощью `ResumeThread()`.

Comment: Спасибо! В моём случае ```join()``` вроде хорошо работает.